# WinRT read from infinite online stream hangs

Tags: c#, http, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

The following code gets a Stream from a URI and will read in in chunks using a loop. Note that behind the specified URI is an online radio stream, which means there is no known size.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://*******", UriKind.Absolute); 
var http = new HttpClient();
var stream = await http.GetStreamAsync(uri);
var buffer = new byte[65536];

while (true)
{
    var read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Debug.WriteLine("Read: {0}", read);
}
```

Now while this works perfectly fine in a .NET 4.5 console app, this exactly same code does not work as expected in WinRT - it will read the first chunk, and when calling ReadAsync for the second time, it will just get stuck and never continue.

If I switch the URI to a file (of known size) everything works fine in both projects.

Any tips?

**EDIT**> note that this behaviour happens only on WP8.1. I just searched some more on SO and found that my question *might* be a duplicate of this one: [WP8.1 HttpClient Stream got only 65536 bytes data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800284/wp8-1-httpclient-stream-got-only-65536-bytes-data) If that is true, I will close my question

Comment: I know this is a hail merry, but have you tried reading in smaller chunks perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Use `HttpClient.GetAsync()` with `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`. That returns when the headers are received, then do `HttpResponse.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync()`.

Comment: 1) HttpResponse.Content does not have a method ReadAsInputStreamAsync.
2) When I use ReadAsStreamAsync, it has the same behaviour, hangs on the second call

Comment: Yes, you have to use `Windows.Web.Http` namespace instead of `System.Net.Http`. Check this example: https://monkeyweekend.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/read-from-infinite-online-stream-using-windows-web-http-httpclient/

Answer (score -2):

Looks like your while loop is infinite. How are you ensuring that it's finite? Instead of while(true) make it something like this

```
var uri = new Uri("http://*******", UriKind.Absolute);
var http = new HttpClient();

var stream = http.GetStreamAsync(uri).Result;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
     while (!reader.EndOfStream)
     {
         var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
     }
}
```